# Filter data based on most recent date and ID in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have data that is structured similarly to the following:

```
a<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,2,2,3,3),Date=as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-03","2017-01-04","2017-01-05","2017-01-06")))
print(a)
ID       Date
1   2017-01-01
2   2017-01-02
2   2017-01-03
2   2017-01-04
3   2017-01-05
3   2017-01-06
```

I want to remove any repeat `ID` and keep the most recent one based on `Date` to obtain the following:

```
b<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3),Date=as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-01-04","2017-01-06")))
print(b)
ID       Date
1   2017-01-01
2   2017-01-04
3   2017-01-06
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `top_n` option discussed in the duplicate link: `a %>% group_by(ID) %>% top_n(1, Date)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do:

`a %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Date == max(Date))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(a)
  a[, max_date := max(Date), by = ID]
  a <- a[max_date == Date, ]
  a[, max_date := NULL]
```

You'll get:

```
    ID       Date
1:  1 2017-01-01
2:  2 2017-01-04
3:  3 2017-01-06
```